# Can a struct file have any name (in this case)?

Tags: ios, swift

While a class usually has the same name as it's contained class - how about the filename of a struct? The below example actually works.

[image]

Comment: The file having the same name as the class is only a convention; you can store any number of different classes in any .swift file, no matter how the file is named.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File names and files themselves are completely arbitrary. You can put multiple object type declarations in one file, and they need have nothing to do with the name of the file. (You can also spread out an object type declaration over multiple files, thanks to extensions.) And the names of those types are *unrelated* to the name of the file.

The reason for giving a file a name that has something to do with its contents is so that *you* can find those contents; it does not affect the behavior or compilation of the program in any way.

Okay, exceptions:

- In Swift, only *main.swift* has special behavior based on its name - and you don't have a *main.swift*.
- Privacy in Swift is file-based, so you want to separate object type declarations that need to keep things private from each other into separate files.

Answer (score 2):

They usually do but in Swift you honestly can call any file anything you want. I have many different files with not directly related names, some with one class, some with multiple, some with just structs, some with class(es) and structs. The new class function in Xcode will give it a specific name but that was never necessary.